# Rails Digital ocean Managed App `extract_credentials_provider': missing credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces, digital-ocean-apps

I'm swimming into Digital ocean managed app since a couple of weeks. SO far everything is working flawlessly. Today I successfully implemented Active storage with Spaces in my local environment using the following configuration:

**storage.yml**

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

digital_ocean:
  service: S3
  endpoint: https://ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:digital_ocean, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:digital_ocean, :secret_access_key) %>
  bucket: my-servername
  region: unused
```

**production.rb / development.rb**

```
  config.active_storage.service = :digital_ocean
```

Where `digital_ocean` config in **credentials.yml** looks like that (before being encrypted) through `EDITOR=VI rails credentials:edit`

```
digital_ocean:
  access_key_id: the_key
  secret_access_key: the_secret
...
```

Locally, everything works like a charm, so I'm assuming it's not about the configuration itself but more about the deployment phase in DO managed app.

## Digital ocean deployment:

```
[2022-02-13 23:34:45] /layers/heroku_ruby/gems/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/aws-sigv4-1.4.0/lib/aws-sigv4/signer.rb:627:in `extract_credentials_provider': missing credentials, provide credentials with one of the following options: (Aws::Sigv4::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
[2022-02-13 23:34:45]   - :access_key_id and :secret_access_key
[2022-02-13 23:34:45]   - :credentials
[2022-02-13 23:34:45]   - :credentials_provider
```

As the whole S3/Space thing works perfectly locally through the same :access_key_id / :secret_access_key mechanism and I can interact with the space from localhost, i'm assuming this issue happens during deploy because rails is not able to decrypt `credentials.yml.enc` file, so I tried 3 things without success:

1. add a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env var at application level
2. adding master.key during build stage by adding the build command in DO settings with `echo "${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}" > config/master.key`
3. adding master.key on the run stage by prepending the run command such as `echo "${RAILS_MASTER_KEY}" > config/master.key && rails server -p $PORT -e ${RAILS_ENV:-production}`

I have been skimming through the internet for hours now and I cannot understand why it would go wrong even tho I'm following all the steps. Something I noticed is the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` Env var does not seem to be available as it doesn't appear when I run `echo $RAILS_MASTER_KEY` in do console, even tho it appears to be set in App Spec env vars:

```
envs:
- key: RAILS_MASTER_KEY
```

Any input infinitely appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Mkay, one have to add to digital ocean app ENV variables the folowing requirements of the [aws-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) (used by heroku during deployment), which are:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your DO space access key id>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= <your DO space secret access key>
```

Hope it helps someone as it's frankly not obvious...